# Tag case sensitivity

Tags: tags, case

At the moment use of Tags seems to be case insensitive.
So, for example, it is possible to tag an article as both 'IT Support' and 'it support'.

Is it at all possible to make the Tags case sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [onBeforeSaveTag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#tags-onBeforeSaveTag) event to capture the tag before it is saved. You can then use PHP's `strtolower` to normalize all of your tags.

In a plugin's main file, your `init()` function should have something like this:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('tags.onBeforeSaveTag', function(Event $event) {
        $event->params['tag']->title = strtolower($event->params['tag']->title);
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks - wonder if it might just be better using categories so that it is much clearer and there is a wee bit more control over the spelling of the 'tags' we want to use

Comment: Sounds like a good option @ColeHenley. Tags are best used when you don't care as much about consistency or organization.